# Does the electrochemical series reverse in electrolysis?

Tags: electrochemistry

Are these two statements true?

1. In a galvanic cell at standard lab conditions (SLC), the strongest reductant is $\ce{Li (s)}$ and the strongest oxidant is $\ce{F2 (g)}$.
2. In an electrolytic cell at SLC, the strongest oxidant is $\ce{Li+ (aq)}$ and the strongest reductant is $\ce{F- (aq)}$.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. States of aggregation should not be subscripted, it is not wrong, but the [recommendations (Sec. 2.1.)](http://pac.iupac.org/publications/pac/pdf/1982/pdf/5406x1239.pdf) are different.

Comment: I thought so but thanks I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, only the first is. The oxidising or reducing property of a species is tied to the species, not to the process in which the species is used. Therefore regardless of whether you are running a galvanic cell or an electrolytic cell, $\ce{F2}$ will always be a strong oxidant and $\ce{Li}$ a strong reductant.

The only difference about the two types of cells is that in the galvanic cell, you are letting the spontaneous cell reaction happen, which produces energy. In the electrolytic cell, you are using energy to force the non-spontaneous cell reaction to happen. The spontaneous cell reaction refers to the direction of the reaction with $\Delta G < 0$ (or equivalently, $E > 0$).

By this, I mean: you can use a galvanic cell to carry out the reaction $\ce{2 Li + F2 -> 2Li+ + 2F-}$. Since $\ce{Li}$ is a strong reductant and $\ce{F2}$ is a strong oxidant, this reaction will generate a lot of energy.

You can use an electrolytic cell to reverse that reaction (although you'd have to use molten and not aqueous $\ce{LiF}$). But since $\ce{Li+}$ is a weak oxidant and $\ce{F-}$ a weak reductant, you're going to need lots of energy to carry that out. Which makes perfect sense!

Comment: SLC is an abbreviation for Standard Lab Conditions; i.e. 25 ºC  temperature and 1 atm pressure.  From what I've read, when you electrolyse molten NaCl, the oxidant is Na$^+$ and the reductant is Cl$^-$. Isn't that consistent with my second statement?

Comment: @inspd I see, the more frequently used abbreviation is STP (standard temperature and pressure). You're right about the identities of the oxidant and reductant, but I think we might have different ideas about what the word "strong" means. If you refer to [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page)), "strong oxidant" means the LHS species for a half-reaction with a large positive $E^\circ$. "Strong reductant" means the RHS species for a half-reaction with a large negative $E^\circ$.

Comment: then it should be "best in the LiF liquid" not "strongest in the chemical series" am I  right ?

Comment: @inspd Essentially that means a strong oxidant is a species that is *easily reduced*, and a strong reductant is a species that is *easily oxidised*. The fact that you would require a lot of energy for the electrolysis of NaCl means that the participating species (Na+ or Cl-) are *hard* to reduce/oxidise - which makes them weak oxidants/reductants.

Comment: so when we electrolyse LiF(l), the best (but weakest) oxidant is:    Li$^+$ and the best (but weakest) reductant is:    F$^-$

Comment: I would rather not use the terms in electrolytic cell at all, for they are misleading. There are no oxidants and reductants here, really. It is electric current that oxidizes and reduces.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So if it is the electric current that oxidises and reduces, then Li isn't an oxidant? You're saying that Li would be described as an oxidant (maybe to make things conceptually easier), but it isn't really oxidising anything, right ?

Comment: Right, so let's stop calling it an oxidant (though nominally it is).

Comment: Haha you can still say that the oxidising / reducing *properties* of the species (ie whether they are strong/weak oxidants/reductants) affects the energy required for the electrolysis, even though they do not *behave* as true oxidants/reductants. Anyway just to sum it up my point is that the direction of the reaction does not affect the order of the electrochemical series. Thanks @IvanNeretin for the explanation

Comment: Makes sense. Also I'll use the terms "best oxidant" and "best reductant" instead (in comparison to other compounds, e.g. $\ce{H2O(l)}$ is the best oxidant in $\ce{NaCl(aq)}$).  Much appreciated @orthocresol and IvanNeretin.

Comment: @inspd You know, that's exactly what he was trying to stop you from doing! Because H2O behaves neither as an oxidant (which is a species that oxidises something else) or a reductant (a species that reduces something else) in the electrolysis. H2O is oxidised and reduced in the electrolysis, but technically it does not carry out the process. So I think he (and I) would prefer if you write "most easily reduced species" and "most easily oxidised species". :)

Comment: Yeh that's what I meant, I gotta watch the semantics.. I'll use what you said, thank you